# Get image from username folder

Tags: php, mysql

hi I am developing a website, that on registration form, takes username password and an image to upload into the database, creating a dedicated folder for each user. Now what I am trying to do is to get the image when the user logs in, obviously the image that should be displayed would be the one of the user uploaded when registering. Is it possible to do so without id but using username folder?
This is how I upload the image.

```
$username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];
$email =  $_POST ['email'];
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];



$s = " select * from usertable where username = '$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){
  echo "Username Already Taken";
}else{
    mkdir("Images/$username", 0777, true);
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"Images/$username/$image");
  $reg= "insert into usertable(username, password, email,imagename) values ('$username', '$password', '$email','$image')";
  mysqli_query($con, $reg);
  echo "registration successfull";
}
```

login form

```
    $username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];



$s = " select * from usertable where username = '$username' && password = '$password'";
$dirname = "images/$username";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){

    $_SESSION['images']= $images;
  $_SESSION['username']= $username;
  header('location:home.php');
}else{
  header('location:index.php');
}
```

Home page

```
<title>Welcome</title>
   </head>
   <body >

 <a href ="logout.php"> Log Out </a>

 <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['images']; ?>"/>

   <h1>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h1>
```

Comment: So, read the username from your database when the user logs in?

Comment: Yes it is possible (if you have the username without it's id...)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have a deadline in 2 days, that's why it was all improvised and it's my first time

Comment: Where is your login code?

Comment: I uploaded the code. My question is, how do i pass the image into a div once I login and get into a new page

Comment: __never__ store plain passwords in your database. use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: in your login you do not really login the user. Neither you write into `$_SESSION` nor do you return a token. So landing on `home.php` you'd have to re-login the user, since you don't know who he/she is.

Comment: and you have a _massive security hole_ there (apart from the already sql-injection): I could upload a php script and _execute_ it! (you gave it 0777, don't check for mimetype/extention/anything)

Comment: I Uploaded everything i've got

Comment: @Werokk which operating system are you using (in which OS your code is running)? Also, are you sure that username folder contains only `.png` files?

Comment: I am running the code on a server. what does the OS have to do with it? yes, there is one image I uploaded and it's .png

Comment: @Werokk OS does play roles when it comes to file systems, for example, *Nix based system consider caps as different i.e, `Images` and `images` folder will be different and can exist in the same location, but on Windows system, both will be treated as same. I saw that you are creating images folder with caps I `mkdir("Images/$username", 0777, true);` and accessing it by using small i, `$dirname = "images/$username";` hence I asked before giving you the exact solution.

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru ok, I get what you trying to say. I tried using I capital letter, as the folder but still no image

Comment: HI @Jeff , when I try to login, it gives me the username. so looks like it's working, when i try to show the image taken from the directory in the server, it doesn't show anything. As i said I am new. how can I fix all these problems?

Comment: @Werokk can you check the output of `$images = glob($dirname."*.png");` by putting this line after `var_dump($images);` and let me know output

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /./.....